# Not able send email to more than recipient using phpMailer even aftre using explode

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I tried to send emails to multiple email address using phpMailer also used explode so as parse the values through an array but nothing worked.
Below is my complete code:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$emailID = $_POST['email'];

$sql = '

    SELECT  *
    FROM    customerEmails
    WHERE   customerEmailID = ' . $emailID . '
    ';

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$contents   = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$to     = $contents['customerEmailTo'];

$from   = $contents['customerEmailFrom'];

$subject= $contents['customerEmailSubject'];

$body   = $contents['customerEmailBody'];


include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pyramid/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pyramid/phpmailer/class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication

$mail->SMTPSecure="tls";

$mail->Host="smtp.office365.com";

$mail->Port=587;

$mail->Username = “xxxxxxx”; // SMTP username

$mail->Password = “xxxxxxxx”; // SMTP password

$webmaster_email = "xxxxxxxx"; //Reply to this email ID

$email=$to; // Recipients email ID

$mail->SMTPDebug = false; //1;

$name=""; // Recipient's name

$mail->From = $webmaster_email;

$mail->FromName = "XYZ";

**$addresses = explode(‘;’,$_POST[‘$to’]);

    foreach ($addresses as $email){
    $mail-> AddAddress($email);
}**

$mail->AddBCC($webmaster_email, "Info");

$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"XYZ");

$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap

//$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz"); // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg"); // attachment

$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;

//$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body

if(!$mail->Send()){

    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

}else{

    //Save date for email sending

    $sqlBlotDate = '

        UPDATE  customeremails

        SET     dateEmailSent = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
        WHERE   customerEmailID = ' . $emailID

    ;
    mysql_query($sqlBlotDate);


    echo "Message has been sent";

}



include 'disconnect.php';
?>
```

Comment: Please include error messages or explain *what exactly* doesn't work.

Comment: It is sending email only to one email address but not to more than one email addresses.

Comment: Try setting `isSMTP(true)`, `Host = 'localhost'` and `SMTPDebug = 2`. That way you will see exactly what's going on between client and server.

Comment: should i make these changes in this code and also if i set Host='localhost' then how would it send the emails? @Synchro

Comment: Yes, all of those things are properties/methods of the PHPMailer instance. You're already using localhost when you send using mail(), as you are at present.

Comment: Sorry, no you're not! Yes, don't use localhost, but do enable debug output so you can see what it's sending.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro but it should the send it to two or more email address when i am parsing the values through a loop like this: $addresses = explode(‘;’,$_POST[‘$to’]);

    foreach ($addresses as $email){
    $mail-> AddAddress($email);
}   //Please help me ,why is this not working??

Comment: As I said, post your debug output.

Comment: It didn't work, it says 500 Internal Server Error for two email addresses but it worked for a single email address. @Synchro

Comment: As always for an error 500 in PHP, you need to either enable error output or look at your server's error log.

Comment: Thanks but can you please tell me how should i do it? @Synchro

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`. Beyond that, [read the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/).